# How to create multiple vertical timeline with child lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timeline

### I'm on a journey ...

trying to create multiple vertical timelines connected through vertical and diagonal timelines.

No resource online has proven this possible in CSS/JavaScript/jQuery to my knowledge.

1 vertical timeline: http://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/

The green boxes are just `<div>` or something that will align to the timeline

### Goal/vision:

http://flerd.se/multiple-timelines.png

Is this even possible or I'm I walking down a dark and lonesome road?

Comment: It is possible with `:after` and `:before` for lines.